# Jquery select between two forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new with javascript and html. I am trying to write a page that, depending on a radio button, displays the correct form. I want to display a form based on the selection of the radio button. I am not sure if I am selecting the right thing with the javascript function. I tried to divide it by divs, but I dont know why it does not work... Here is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=select]:radio').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "Yes") {
      $('form[name="Computerform"]').hide();
      $('form[name="VMform"]').show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "No") {
      $('form[name="Computerform"]').hide();
      $('form[name="VMform"]').show();
    }


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="main">
    <form name="select">
      <input type="radio" name="A" value="No">Yes
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="A" value="Yes">No
    </form>

    <div id="first">
      <form action="process.php" name="Computerform" method="get">
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Your Name" id="firstName" />
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Your Last Name" id="LastName" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
      <form action="process.php" name="VMform" method="get">
        <strong>Favorite Color: </strong>
        <select name="color" id="color">
          <option value="">Select a Color</option>
          <option value="Red">Red</option>
          <option value="Green">Green</option>
          <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Can someone explain me, how I ll change the code to do this behavior? I just want to display one form depending on what the user choose in the first form (the radio buttoms).
Thank you!

Comment: There's no element `input[name=select]` in your code.

Comment: thanks! I ll changed it, but it is showing both forms :/ so it looks that this is not the problem.

Comment: I ll changed it to: 'form[name="select"]:radio'. but it does not work :/

Comment: `$( ":radio" ) is equivalent to $( "[type=radio]" )` You still have **no** element which is `form` with name `select` and with type `radio`.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <button  type="button">Click here</button>

    <div class="form-computer">
        <form action="process.php" name="Computerform" method="get">   
            <strong>First Name: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Your Name" id="firstName"/>
            <strong>First Name: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Your Last Name" id="LastName"/> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="process.php" name = "VMform" method="get">
            <strong>Favorite Color: </strong>
            <select name="color" id="color">
            <option value="">Select a Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.form-computer').toggle("slow");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give your form that contains the radio buttons an ID and target them in the jquery: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxcuw2s7/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formID input").click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "Yes") {
            $('form[name="Computerform"]').hide();
            $('form[name="VMform"]').show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "No") {
            $('form[name="Computerform"]').show();
            $('form[name="VMform"]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer to question in comment. Hide one form at the beginning with CSS:

```
form[name="VMform"] {display: none;}
```

Also, I swapped the hide/show at the bottom. I assumed "no" should do the opposite of when "yes" is clicked.

Comment: thank you! But, at the beggining, both forms are showing. How I can take one out?

Comment: Please see updated answer and fiddle which addresses this question.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id = "main">
    <form name="select">
        <input type="radio" name="A" value="1">show first form<br>
        <input type="radio" name="A" value="2">show second form 
    </form> 

    <div id = "first">
        <form action="process.php" name="Computerform" method="get">   
            <strong>First Name: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Your Name" id="firstName"/>
            <strong>First Name: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Your Last Name" id="LastName"/> 
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id = "second">
        <form action="process.php" name = "VMform" method="get">
            <strong>Favorite Color: </strong>
            <select name="color" id="color">
            <option value="">Select a Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form[name="select"] :radio').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
            $('#first').show();
            $('#second').hide();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
            $('#first').hide();
            $('#second').show();
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#first, #second{display:none;}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abrhmcc/poze8vj0/3/

Comment: Also thanks to you, but I Don't want that both forms to show at the beggining. How I can achieve this? (Hide at least one at the begging)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="A"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
      $('form[name="Computerform"]').hide();
      $('form[name="VMform"]').show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "No") {
      $('form[name="VMform"]').hide();
      $('form[name="Computerform"]').show();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="main">
    <form name="select">
      <input type="radio" name="A" value="No">Yes
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="A" value="Yes">No
    </form>

    <div id="first">
      <form action="process.php" name="Computerform" method="get">
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Your Name" id="firstName" />
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Your Last Name" id="LastName" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
      <form action="process.php" name="VMform" method="get">
        <strong>Favorite Color: </strong>
        <select name="color" id="color">
          <option value="">Select a Color</option>
          <option value="Red">Red</option>
          <option value="Green">Green</option>
          <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the HTML like this:

```
<div id = "main">
<form name="select">
    <input type="radio" name="A" value="Yes">Show the first form<br>
    <input type="radio" name="A" value="No">Show the second form 
</form> 

<div id = "first">
    <form action="process.php" name="Computerform" method="get">   
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Your Name" id="firstName"/>
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Your Last Name" id="LastName"/> 
    </form>
</div>

<div id = "second">
    <form action="process.php" name = "VMform" method="get">
        <strong>Favorite Color: </strong>
        <select name="color" id="color">
        <option value="">Select a Color</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JS like this:

```
$('form[name="select"] :radio').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="Yes"){
        $('#first').show();
        $('#second').hide();

    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="No"){
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').show();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use change instead of click. Also val() method is to get the current value (value attribute != value property). And the bonus: you can use shorter version to toggle div :)

```
$('input[name="test"]').change( function() {
    $('#toggle').toggle( $(this).val() === 'yes');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjzre7sf/1/)

Comment: Hi and thanks! What is the difference between toggle and click? Also, How I can make it using slide up and down animation (jquery)? And, last request, if I have 2 forms, and you want to toggle between them? you just do: form[name="VMform"] {display: none;} right? is that the correct way?

Comment: Difference between change and click is that the click event is fired every time you click the input layer or any layer above, even if it not change the input value. To use slideToggle unfortunately, you need to use the if statement. About last question - look the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hjzre7sf/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="VMform"]').hide();
    $('#r1').click(function(){
            $('form[name="Computerform"]').hide();
            $('form[name="VMform"]').show();
    });

    $('#r2').click(function(){
            $('form[name="Computerform"]').show();
            $('form[name="VMform"]').hide();
    });
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/few5bm0u/

It looks like yo are always hiding the same one.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to JavaScript and HTML (I assume you like to learn)
There are many great libraries like JQuery, [UnderscoreJs](http://underscorejs.org/) and frameworks like [AngulerJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) that can make life a little more easy.

But more interesting is using plain HTML, CSS and Javascript, this will give you a better understanding of how the DOM works. The libraries are there to support compatibility between browsers and simplify some tasks.

Now lets apply this to your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/m6s6a63n/

CSS:

```
.myforms.no { display: block; }
.myforms.no .yes { display: none; }

.myforms.yes { display: block; }
.myforms.yes .no { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll('form[name=select] input[type=radio]');
   var myforms = document.querySelector('.myforms');

   [].forEach.call(elements, function (element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', function () {
          myforms.setAttribute('class', 'myforms ' + this.value);
      })
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myforms">
<form name="select">
    <input type="radio" name="A" value="no">Yes</input><br>
    <input type="radio" name="A" value="yes">No</input>
</form>

<div class="yes">
    <form action="process.php" name="Computerform" method="get">
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Your Name" id="firstName" />
        <strong>First Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Your Last Name" id="LastName" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="no">
    <form action="process.php" name="VMform" method="get">
        <strong>Favorite Color: </strong>
        <select name="color" id="color">
            <option value="">Select a Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```